# How to compare 2 Dataframes of unequal length based on Datetime column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have 2 Dataframes and I want to remove the rows from `badges` dataframe who have the value of `Date` greater than the respective `UserId's` `date` field from `test_df` dataframe. The problem is that both dataframes have multiple values for `UserId` and the total number of rows of both dataframes are unequal. The code that I used works only if both dataframes have equal number of rows, otherwise it produces an error.

**Part of badges**

```
UserId | Date
101    | 2009-09-01 15:17:50.660
101    | 2009-09-01 15:17:50.660
101    | 2009-09-02 15:17:50.660
102    | 2009-09-03 15:17:50.660
103    | 2013-09-30 15:17:50.660
103    | 2013-09-30 15:17:50.660
104    | 2009-09-30 15:17:50.660
```

**Part of test_df**

```
UserId | date
101    | 2010-09-01 15:17:50.660
101    | 2010-09-02 15:17:50.660
101    | 2010-09-03 15:17:50.660
102    | 2010-09-30 15:17:50.660
103    | 2010-09-30 15:17:50.660
103    | 2010-09-30 15:17:50.660
```

**Code**

```
badges = badges[(badges.Date < test_df.date)]
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

**Required Output**

```
badges

UserId     | Date
    101    | 2009-09-01 15:17:50.660
    101    | 2009-09-01 15:17:50.660
    101    | 2009-09-02 15:17:50.660
    102    | 2009-09-03 15:17:50.660
    104    | 2009-09-30 15:17:50.660
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the dates to datetime :

```
badges["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(badges["Date"])
test_df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(test_df["date"])
```

Iterate to get values where badges date is less than test_df date :
from itertools import product

```
valid_dates = {
    badge_date
    for badge_date, test_df_date in product(badges.Date.unique(), test_df.date.unique())
    if badge_date < test_df_date
}
```

Filter badges with valid_dates :

```
badges.loc[badges["Date"].isin(valid_dates)]

    UserId  Date
0   101     2009-09-01 15:17:50.660
1   101     2009-09-01 15:17:50.660
2   101     2009-09-02 15:17:50.660
3   102     2009-09-03 15:17:50.660
6   104     2009-09-30 15:17:50.660
```